# Calling second function in first function

Tags: javascript

I have particular function named `profilefrm()` in which I am checking conditions returning true or false,  I have created another function `checkcontacts()`. I have called this function in first one. I have successfully returning true or false from second one. I have flow is

```
function profilefrm(){
if condition1{
// on false 
returning false;
}
checkcontacts();
}

function checkcontacts(){
if condition1{
// on false 
returning false;
}
return true;
}
```

But issue is on false condition in second function it is taken as true in first one. and refreshing page accordingly.

Comment: Can you please provide us with original code ?

Comment: I think you forgot to return the return value from checkcontracts in profilefrm. You're now just calling the function but not returning it's result from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could return the result of the `checkcontacts` function:

```
function profilefrm() {
    if (condition1) {
        // on false 
        return false;
    }

    return checkcontacts();
}
```

Comment: But as I am calling function `checkcontacts()` in middle of function `profilefrm()` so if `checkcontacts()` return true it will also return true in mid of function `profilefrm()`

Comment: @RahulSingh, in this case assign the result of the `checkcontact` to a variable that you could use later when returning: `var result = checkcontacts();`.

Comment: What would happen false or true will be stored in result. what happen on both conditions.?

Comment: @RahulSingh, this will depend on what the `checkcontacts` function returns.

Comment: on false condition from second one. it will return false at that moment. but in case if it return true than I need to check rest conditions written in profilefrm() after checkcontacts().

Comment: @RahulSingh, well then test the returned value and if it is true continue with the flow: `if (result) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

function's return value should specify. function do no return if not specify.

```
firtst function change to below.

function profilefrm(){
    if condition1{
        // on false 
        returning false;
    }
    return checkcontacts();
}
```